# Laravel X-Jet components renders HTML as <x-jet-component> directly when interpolating parameters on them parsed from PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Im currently struggling getting my Laravel **X-Jet components** to behave.

Say I have a form with a component called `<x-jet-input>` in it.

Normally when I use this component like this:

```php-template
<x-jet-input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="..." value="{{ old('name', $team->name) }}" autofocus/>
```

The HTML becomes this when I run it:

```html
<input class="..." id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Output from PHP" autofocus="autofocus">
```

###### Now here is where the issue comes in:

If I add certain parameters that are interpolated from PHP; Like `disabled`:

```php-template
<x-jet-input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="..." value="{{ old('name', $team->name) }}" {{ 'disabled' }} autofocus />
```

The rendered HTML output suddenly becomes this:

```html
<x-jet-input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="..." value="Output from PHP" disabled="" autofocus=""></x-jet-input>
```

The whole element has turned into a `<x-jet-input>` on the raw HTML. I don't understand why, and the result is that the rendered output on the page is completely non-functional.

Here is what the component code looks like:

```php-template
@props(['disabled' => false])

<input {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => '...']) !!}>
```

*PS: Classes replaced with `...` for readability.*

I also ran into this same issue with `x-jet-checkbox` component. Trying to use the `checked` attribute.

What am I missing here?

I tried to manually add the component `props` value, and code the appropriate behavior directly into the component (Instead of relying on `$attributes->merge()`). This have the same result. It does not change the output.

If I put the `disabled` attribute in this case, directly in (without PHP interpolation):

```php-template
<x-jet-input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="..." value="{{ old('name', $team->name) }}" disabled autofocus />
```

Everything works fine, and the HTML renders as normal:

```html
<input disabled="" class="..." id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Output from PHP" autofocus="autofocus">
```

When I put PHP interpolation: I expect it to behave the same. But it doesn't. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this same issue on a [different forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-x-jet-components-renders-html-as-x-jet-component-directly-when-interpolating-parameters-on-them-parsed-from-php), and someone gave me a pointer.

When working with Blade components: Anything that is interpolated with PHP needs to be prefixed with a `:` first before it's attribute name.

So my solution is very simple:

```php-template
<x-jet-input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="..." value="{{ old('name', $team->name) }}" :disabled="$disabled" autofocus />
```

See the Laravel documentation here for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components